# Is having multiple producers for the same topic in Azure Service Bus problematic?

Tags: azure-servicebus-queues, azure-servicebus-topics

In my application, there are two independent sources that could produce the same message type. I know there are not going to be any duplicate messages from the two sources, and the consumers don't care which source the message came from. So it makes a lot of sense to have both of the producers insert messages into the same topic.

I was just wondering if there are any potential issues when having competing producers. I have been reading the documentation but didn't find any information on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In messaging it is accepted thay any number of producers can send messages to the same queue. But the queue guarantees that each message is processed by a single consumer. Some nuance here, as we can have multiple subscribers.

I.e. there is no issue based on your assertions. A matter of style for some though.

Where I am now we write many different messages to a same topic that can be parsed into different messages when being consumed. One can argue with that, but products like KAFKA Connect give you the option to write different data to same Topic.

https://medium.com/event-driven-utopia/the-stuff-that-every-developer-should-know-about-message-queues-a9452ac9c9d

Comment: Thanks for the details. But the link you shared is not specifically about Azure Service Bus.

Comment: True but it is based on principles that apply to any such product I would counter.

Answer (score 1):

From a technical point of view, there's no issue with having multiple publishers publishing to the same Service Bus topic. That's what topics are for.

From a logical point of view, there's some question around "competing publishers" as it in odds with the real world. You have competing consumers, that compete over the same messages. Publishers could be scaled out but publishing the same message (information) from more than a single instance feels off.

Comment: I may have not used the best wording, but in my app, I know different publishers won't publish the exact same message. What I meant was multiple publishers trying to insert different messages in the same topic at the same time.

Comment: In that case the answer I've provided stays the same. That's exactly what topics and queues are for.